# Display list of files from directory with checkboxes

Tags: php, file, checkbox, directory

I am trying to display a list of all the .txt files in a directory with check-boxes next to each file.  Then select the check-boxes for the files you want and the next process will delete those files from the directory.  I have the following code to display the files in the directory, but don't know how to create the check-boxes next to the file names.

```
// Define the full path to your folder from root 
$path = "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/Members/$company/Users/$insp_name/Orders/Clients"; 

// Open the folder 
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path"); 

// Loop through the files 
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
  if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" ) 
    continue; 

  echo "$file<br />";
}

// Close 
closedir($dir_handle);
```

Comment: what names/values do you want the checkboxes to have?

Comment: You might also want to add `is_file($file)` to your if statement to make sure that it's a file and not a directory.

Comment: @Jason, could you share the entire code, I need to do the same, but instead of deleting the selected files, I need to "cat" them into a bigger file.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: In the following `if` block, use braces around the `continue` for clarity.  Otherwise, it looks like the `echo` happens inside the `if` block rather than after it has completed.

```
if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" ) 
{
  continue; 
}
// Prints a checkbox after each file.
// The checkboxes are received by the form handler as an array called $files[]
// holding the filenames of the files you want deleted.
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='files[]' value='$file' /> $file<br />\n";
```

Now on your form handling script:

```
$path = "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/Members/$company/Users/$insp_name/Orders/Clients";
foreach($_POST['files'] as $filename) {
  // To prevent traversal attacks, you need to validate $filename
  // For example, if it would only be expected to be alphanumeric:
  if (ctype_alnum($filename)) {
    if(!unlink($path . "/" . $filename)) {
       echo "Error deleting $filename";
    }
  }
}
```

Note about validation: It is very important to validate the contents of `$filename` to ensure it doesn't contain null bytes or `../../../` to permit modification of files outside the intended path.  In the example above that was done with `ctype_alnum()`, but different regular expressions or `in_array()` may be more appropriate for a given situation.

Comment: Do I have to open up the directory again on the form handler so it knows where to delete the files from?  Cause right now when I goto my form handling script/page I'm getting the "Error deleting $filename" message.

Comment: @Jason You don't need to open the directory again, but you will need the `$path`.  See edit...

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<input type="checkbox" name="files" value="whatever" /> ' . $file . '<br />';`

That should create a `checkbox` element next to each file in your list.

Also, note that your code formatting is quite confusing - the `continue` makes it look as if it will run every iteration, no matter what. Consider putting it on the same line as the the `if` statement, or on the line below, indented appropriately. Or put it in `{ }`.

Comment: Small correction, $file will be outputted as "$file" because when you echo with single quotes (') PHP doesn't replace them. You should add change it to  `echo '<input type="checkbox" name="files" value="whatever" />'.$file.'<br />';`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your echo statement with this:

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"files[]\" value=\"$file\">$file<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo an INPUT element right before outputting the name of the file

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$file\" name=\"files[]\" />$file<br />";
```

**You might also want to add `! is_file($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file)` to your if statement to make sure that it's a file and not a directory.**

```
if ( $file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" || ! is_file($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file) )
```